# Are my p-values really this small or is my R code wrong?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, p-value, fishers-exact-test

Here is my R code:

```
x <- matrix(c( 32, 15, 7, 17, 24, 68,
                3,  2, 1, 10,  4,  9,
               10, 13, 6, 11,  4, 24,
                2,  1, 0,  3,  1,  4,
              197,108,40,208,109,133), ncol=6, byrow=T)
x = as.table(x)
names(dimnames(x)) = c("Party", "Theme")
rownames(x)        = c("Conservative","Crossbench","Labor","Lib.Dem","NA")
colnames(x)        = c("Econ","Regs","Scots","Macro.Prud","Pens","Decs")
addmargins(x)
#               Theme
# Party          Econ Regs Scots Macro.Prud Pens Decs  Sum
#   Conservative   32   15     7         17   24   68  163
#   Crossbench      3    2     1         10    4    9   29
#   Labor          10   13     6         11    4   24   68
#   Lib.Dem         2    1     0          3    1    4   11
#   NA            197  108    40        208  109  133  795
#   Sum           244  139    54        249  142  238 1066
chisq.test(x) 
chisq.test(x,  simulate.p.value=T, B=10000) 
fisher.test(x, simulate.p.value=T, B=10000)
```

When I run this code for that matrix, as well as for a number of other I get p-values that are very very small (`3.563e-09`, `9.999e-05` and `9.999e-05` respectively for the three tests).

Are these correct (can someone check)? Is there a problem in my R code?

Comment: One related piece of information is that you are heartily breaking the chi-square rule of thumb: no cell should have fewer than 5 observations.

Comment: @lmo that is why the OP is not relying on asymptotics but using simulation.

Comment: I am not close to a machine to rerun your code but it looks OK to me. But I am a human not a computer.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks for the tip. I'm a bit skeptical about the ability of Monte Carlo methods to overcome instances where 0 observations are present in a cell, but I'm not familiar with this method.  The R help page on `?chisq.test` says "In the contingency table case simulation is done by random sampling from the set of all contingency tables with given marginals, and works only if the marginals are strictly positive." This condition  is certainly satisfied here.

Comment: What are the variables here? The row names give me the impression that they are different levels of a categorical variable, but the column names don't make any sense as levels of a single variable. Is each column supposed to be a different variable?

Comment: @gung I can tell you the context of the data. The data had already been run through a text analysis programme to produce thematic clusters, those are the labels across the top. Political parties are down the vertical axis. The number of times each party speaks on the topic is in each cell. I was testing to see if there is a statistically significant difference between parties in terms of the amount they discuss each topic (could be an indicator of how partisan).

Comment: Is `NA` a political party in England? What is the `crossbench` party?

Comment: @gung Crossbencher is a house of lords member who does not directly represent one part, NA is non-affiliated.

Comment: It sure seems like an awful lot of British MPs are not affiliated w/ a political party. I thought all were, although I'm not British, so maybe I just don't know.

Comment: The actual p-values may be substantially smaller than you're getting in the second and third case.

Comment: @gung I think from his comment about house of lords that some of these sit in our upper chamber where crossbenchers do exist.

Comment: @gung Yes this whole table is from the Lords Economic Affairs Committee and hence takes place in the upper chamber (House of Lords). I have separate data to run through the same analysis but from the Treasury Select Committee, which takes place in the lower chamber (House of Commons).

Comment: The rule of thumb @lmo alludes to is for _expected_ frequencies, not observed. It's hyperconservative: so long as expected frequencies are $\ge 1$ things are usually all right.

Comment: (1) There seem to be a lot of non-affiliated Lords - most Lords are either in a party or the cross-bench "party". (2) What are you counting anyway? There aren't 1066 Lords & certainly not 1066 on that committee. If you're counting speeches then speeches given by the same Lord are hardly independent.

Comment: @Scortchi It's a committee so the non-affiliated members are members of the Bank of England's Monetary policy committee - I coded the word party as it is easier than saying "group of committee members with different affiliations". It is not speeches. I took the I.C.U.s from transcripts between 2010-2015 and used t-lab to find the E.C.U.s. Then I categorised the E.C.U.s into thematic clusters, then checked the compositions of each thematic cluster as seen above.

Comment: (1) Makes sense. (2) Transcripts of what? The point, anyway, is whether or not you're counting multiple *somethings* by the same person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't necessarily see anything wrong with what you've done.

```
chisq.test(x) 
#  Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  x
# X-squared = 80.248, df = 20, p-value = 3.563e-09
# 
# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(x) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
set.seed(3689)  # this makes the test exactly reproducible
chisq.test(x,  simulate.p.value=T, B=10000) 
#  Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value
#   (based on 10000 replicates)
# 
# data:  x
# X-squared = 80.248, df = NA, p-value = 9.999e-05
set.seed(5161)
fisher.test(x, simulate.p.value=T, B=10000) 
#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated
#   p-value (based on 10000 replicates)
# 
# data:  x
# p-value = 9.999e-05
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

The code isn't that difficult to call.  You did drop the `c` from the inputted vector in `matrix`, but I suspect that happened somehow in pasting your code into your question here since otherwise you wouldn't have been able to run the code at all.

Remember that the chi-squared test is just comparing the observed counts to the expected counts under independence.  You can see those with:

```
round(chisq.test(x)$expected, 1) 
#                Theme
# Party           Econ  Regs Scots Macro.Prud  Pens  Decs
#   Conservative  37.3  21.3   8.3       38.1  21.7  36.4
#   Crossbench     6.6   3.8   1.5        6.8   3.9   6.5
#   Labor         15.6   8.9   3.4       15.9   9.1  15.2
#   Lib.Dem        2.5   1.4   0.6        2.6   1.5   2.5
#   NA           182.0 103.7  40.3      185.7 105.9 177.5
```

Because independence implies the number in each cell is just the row probability times the column probability as a proportion of the total count, you can easily compute those yourself to check.  (Although this isn't something R is going to get wrong.)

```
rs = rowSums(x)/sum(x);  rs
# Conservative   Crossbench        Labor      Lib.Dem 
#   0.15290807   0.02720450   0.06378987   0.01031895 
cs = colSums(x)/sum(x);  cs
#       Econ       Regs      Scots Macro.Prud       Pens       Decs
# 0.22889306 0.13039400 0.05065666 0.23358349 0.13320826 0.22326454
round(rs%*%t(cs), 3)
#       Econ  Regs Scots Macro.Prud  Pens  Decs
# [1,] 0.035 0.020 0.008      0.036 0.020 0.034
# [2,] 0.006 0.004 0.001      0.006 0.004 0.006
# [3,] 0.015 0.008 0.003      0.015 0.008 0.014
# [4,] 0.002 0.001 0.001      0.002 0.001 0.002
# [5,] 0.171 0.097 0.038      0.174 0.099 0.167
all.equal(as.vector(rs%*%t(cs)*sum(x)), as.vector(chisq.test(x)$expected))
# [1] TRUE
```

The formula for the chi-squared test is very simple at this point:
$$
\newcommand{\Obs}{{\rm Obs}}
\newcommand{\Exp}{{\rm Exp}}
\chi^2 = \sum \frac{(\Obs_{ij}-\Exp_{ij})^2}{\Exp_{ij}}
$$ 
So you can do this manually, if you want to check:

```
Exp = as.vector(chisq.test(x)$expected)
sum( (as.vector(x)-Exp)^2/Exp )  # [1] 80.24779
```

The degrees of freedom for a chi-squared test of a two-way contingency table is $(r-1)(c-1) = 4\times 5 = 20$.  The value of the test statistic for your table is really far out for a $\chi^2_{df=20}$.

```
1-pchisq(80.248, df=20)  # [1] 3.563094e-09
xs = seq(from=0, to=85, by=.1)
windows()
  plot(xs, dchisq(xs, df=20), type="l")
  abline(h=0, col="gray")
  lines(xs, dchisq(xs, df=20))
  segments(x0=80, y0=0, y1=0.002, col="red")
```

[image]

So this all makes perfect sense to me.  The only problem is that the sampling distribution of the test statistic isn't well approximated by the chi-squared distribution when you have a lot of very low expected counts (you have 1 <1, and 10 <5).  That's where the simulation comes in, but that's fine here too.

Basically, it is just really unlikely to get a table that looks like yours if the variables were unrelated.  To understand why the discrepancy is coming from, it may help you to plot:

```
windows()
  mosaicplot(x, shade=TRUE)
```

[image]

Basically, the conservatives and labor are talking about decisions more than you'd expect, and the conservatives are talking less about macro prudential and the NA party is talking less about decisions than you'd expect under independence.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was correct but had never received p-values so low before, so thank you for confirming. That Mosaic is very useful too. Many thanks.